# How can I loop for end of month date between to dates in sh?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I want to loop and print end of month date between two dates.

I have below code but it prints day on day.

```
startdate='2021-01-01'
enddate='2021-04-01'

enddate=$( date -d "$enddate + 1 day" +%Y%m%d )   # rewrite in YYYYMMDD format
                                                  #  and take last iteration into account
thedate=$( date -d "$startdate" +%Y%m%d )
while [ "$thedate" != "$enddate" ]; do
    printf 'The date is "%s"\n' "$thedate"
    thedate=$( date -d "$thedate + 1 days" +%Y%m%d ) # increment by one day
done
```

but I want these result for:

```
  startdate='2021-01-01'
    enddate='2021-04-01'
```

> 20210131

> 20210228

> 20210331

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this

```
    year=$(date +%Y)
for month in {01..04}; {
    day=($(cal -d $year-$month))
    echo "$year$month${day[@]:(-1)}"
}
20210131
20210228
20210331
20210430
```

or with -m flag

```
year=$(date +%Y)
for month in {01..04}; {
    day=($(cal -m $month $year))
    echo "$year$month${day[@]:(-1)}"
}
20210131
20210228
20210331
20210430
```

Comment: What version of `cal` supports the `-d` flag? My `cal` is 2.33.1 and does not have it.

Comment: I've got gnome-calendar 3.36.1-linuxmint1

Answer (score 1):

Using `date` command :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
  
startdate=$1
enddate=$2

while true; do
    month_end=$(date -d "${startdate::6}01 +1month -1day" +%Y%m%d)
    [[ $month_end -lt $enddate ]] && echo $month_end || break
    startdate=$(date -d "$month_end +1day" +%Y%m%d)
done
```

Calling method

```
$ ./test.sh 20210101 20210401
20210131
20210228
20210331
```